# Selecting folder

Tags: vba, file, button, directory, picker

I'm working with msoFileDialogFolderPicker for picking folder on my access form via vba but it is not selecting folder but just files, my syntax is as follow :

```
Private Sub micHyperlink_Click()

    Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker As Long = 3

   Dim fd As Object
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
   With fd
'Set the initial path to the D:\Documents\ folder.
    InitialFileName = "T:\=??????-????? ?????=\Current year\MOCVD\Data Collection\Characterization tool\Microscope"
   .Title = "Select Attachment Link"
'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
'If the user presses the action button...
   If .Show = -1 Then
'   DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
   Me![microscope_Images] = "#" & .SelectedItems(1) & "#"

'  **

'If the user presses Cancel...
   Else
   End If
 End With

'Set the object variable to Nothing.
   Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please your help will be more than appreciated

Comment: Remove your Const definition: `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` is already defined by VBA, no need to define it manually. And its value is 4, not 3 - 3 is `msoFileDialogFilePicker` - which explains your issue.

Comment: FunThomas, thank you very much , it is working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as quick answer - as already written as comment:

a) The constants for then `Application.FileDialog` are already defined by VBA, there is no need to define them in the code. They are

`msoFileDialogFilePicker` (3) to select file(s)
`msoFileDialogFolderPicker` (4) to select a folder
`msoFileDialogOpen` (1) to open file(s)
`msoFileDialogSaveAs` (2) to select a filename for saving

b) The value for msoFileDialogFolderPicker is 4, but you defined it as 3. This overwrites the VBA definition and creates a FilePicker-Dialog (3)

Conclusion: Just remove the `Const`-definition in your code.